# Is this definition of orthogonal complement well-defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U$ a subspace. The codimension of $U$ is defined to be the dimension of the quotient $V/U$.

I am wondering if the following definition would be well-defined:

The codimension of $U$ in $V$ is the dimension of any subspace $W$ of $V$ such that $V = U \oplus W$.

Answer (score 0):

By axiom of choice, any linear subspace has a complement. So your definition makes sense provided you admit axiom of choice. But you can't say the complement is "orthogonal" because your vector space doesn't even have an inner product..

By the way, the codimension can be infinite. But if you consider it as the cardinality of any Hamel basis of your complement, it still makes sense.